# I want to acheve this effect of trees changing texture based on distance to the player

Tags: textures, godot

The effect also applies to mountains and terrain, trees in the back look like shadows which with a dark sky look nice and in the day I can make them look like grey fog. I was thinking of simply adding a tween and slowly change the texture as the player gets closer or further... except there's only problem?

How do I get the player distance? I've already tried similar things and getting the distance between two nodes ends up lagging a lot, by using areas just one check per frame is enough to destroy my frame rate on my other computer or straight up crash the game on this other one... by using `get_tree().get_node()` it get's better but still causes performance issues and using a timer instead of `_physics_process()` mitigates the problem a little bit...but if there are more than a few trees or heels, the problem comes back.

[image: screenshot showing problem]

Answer (score 3):

You want to do this in the material applied to the meshes.

The idea is to take the distance to the camera for the fragment, and use that to decide how to color it.

To get the distance to the camera we can use `length(VERTEX)`, and to use that to decide what color to use we can use a combination of `mix` and `step` (or `smoothstep`):

```
shader_type spatial;

uniform sampler2D texture_away: source_color;
uniform sampler2D texture_near : source_color;
uniform float dist;

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = mix(
        texture(texture_near, UV),
        texture(texture_away, UV),
        step(dist, length(VERTEX))
    ).rgb;
}
```

So where the distance is less than `dist` you get `texture_near`, but when it is away you get `texture_away`.

**Notes**:

- You would need to set values for the uniforms under "Shader parameters" in the inspector.
- Below I explain that adding this effect is easier with material overlay. Howver, if you cannot use material overlay, you would have to modify the materials you have to include a modified version of the code above. The gist of it is that instead of `texture(texture_near, UV)` you want to put whatever they were setting to `ALBEDO` before.
- It is also possible to use a color uniform instead of a texture, which I'll do for the overlay version below.
- You can also modify the above code to use `smoothstep` instead of `step`. There is an example of using `smoothstep` at the end of the answer.

---

I suppose you want to combine this with other effects. So… The easier way would be to apply it as material overlay (a material set in `material_overlay`)… In which case we want the case where you are near be transparent. So we could do this:

```
shader_type spatial;

uniform vec3 color: source_color;
uniform float dist;

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = color;
    ALPHA = mix(
        0.0,
        1.0,
        step(dist, length(VERTEX))
    );
}
```

This way, when it is close to the camera you see `color`, and when it is away you get transparency, which in a material overlay leaves whatever color was there.

By the way, we actually don't need `mix` in this case, we can do this instead:

```
shader_type spatial;

uniform vec3 color: source_color;
uniform float dist;

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = color;
    ALPHA = step(dist, length(VERTEX));
}
```

Now for an smooth transition we do this:

```
shader_type spatial;

uniform vec3 color: source_color;
uniform float start_dist;
uniform float end_dist;

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = color;
    ALPHA = smoothstep(start_dist, end_dist, length(VERTEX));
}
```

Here you get no effect up until `start_dist`. Between `start_dist` and `end_dist` you get a smooth transition between that to `color`. And beyond `end_dist` you only get `color`.

I hope this is clear enough for you to add to your project.